# Is it possible to alias variables with terraform?

Tags: terraform

To get the current AWS id I do:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" { }
```

Which makes it available in `data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id`. Is there some way to make it available as just `account_id`? I tried:

```
variable "account_id" {
  default = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
}
```

but it says I can't do string interpolation in variables.

Answer (score 7):

Since [0.10.3](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0103-august-30-2017), you can use [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) to get around the lack of variable interpolation.

This allows you to define a "friendly" name for all sorts of things that might require interpolation.

In your case you would simply use:

```
locals {
  account_id = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
}
```

But you can combine any amount of interpolations and functions:

```
variable "foo" {}
variable "bar" {}

locals {
  account_id = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
  foo_BAR    = "${var.foo}_${upper(var.bar)}"
}
```

---

#### Old answer

As Terraform points out in your error, you can't do variable interpolation directly although there are [known hacky workarounds](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4084) for when you need some form of variable interpolation.

Unfortunately all of these involve slightly convoluted uses of modules, templates or the `null_resource` or `null_data_source` which would then still leave you accessing the variable in an awkward way.

One option that might be more palatable for you is to wrap a bunch of data sources into a module like this:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
output "account_id" { value = "data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id" }

data "aws_availability_zones" "zones" {}
output "zones" { value = "data.aws_availability_zones.zones.names }
```

And then access these like so:

```
module "data_sources" {
    source = "path/to/data-sources-module.tf"
}

...
    account_id = "${module.data_sources.account_id}"
...
    availability_zone = "${module.data_sources.zones[0]}"
```

But that doesn't really make these values as easily exposed as intermediate variables unfortunately.